# How I can add custom whois server to WHMCS

Tags: api, whois, whmcs

How we can add custom whois server to WHMCS. I've an API access for ccTLD domain and want to add whois server from API.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit /includes/whoisservers.php and add an entry in the format:

```
.extension|whois server|match string
```

Comment: What's the `HTTPREQUEST-` string that is present on the default file on whmcs?